# how can i click on image using selenium webdriver in c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to implement a automatic test using selenium webdriver with c#.
My page has this image button made with JavaScript on right bottom corner.

MY HTML Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sanofi - Digital Value Chain</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon-sanofi.png">

<link href="styles.e3154dfb8e8b22c30979.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
<body>
  <app-root>Automatic testing page - Chatbot with Selenium + C# </app-root>

  <!-- Avaamo Chatbot -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var AvaamoChatBot=function(t){function o(t,o){var n=document.createElement("script");n.setAttribute("src",t),n.onload=o,document.body.appendChild(n)}return this.options=t||{},this.load=function(t){o(this.options.url,function(){window.Avaamo.addFrame(),t&&"function"==typeof(t)&&t(window.Avaamo)})},this};
  var chatBox = new AvaamoChatBot({url: 'https://c0.avaamo.com/web_channels/47afd7fd-6473-445a-bb87-4b4c46c51b94?locale=eng&bot_typing_duration=60000'});
  chatBox.load();
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.c239ca988071a28dfcf5.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.1c766e36408e34083505.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.c7b8f195ebee14d64454.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.b1d0922e092ba105d6d7.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.44cb2cdc7217ee361473.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

So, i am trying with this C# code, but it is not working.

```
//Create the reference for our browser
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

//Navigate to LANDING PAGE
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BOT_ADDRESS_LOCAL_DISC);

//Maximize window       
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

//Aguarda 3 segundos até carregar o BOT
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

//Find and click on CHATBOT Button
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("text/javascript")).Click();

//Wait until load all details.
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Does anyone has a solution for that???

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cssSelector:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("script[type='text/javascript']")).Click();
```

Comment: i got a error on my C# code when i did this.

OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 'element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)'

Comment: It seems you need to wait until the element is visible before interacting with it. There is an 'Expected Conditions' class that does this.

Comment: Yes you can increase it but instead of `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)`, use the ExpectedConditions class so that you only wait until the element is available, not just waiting for a fixed time.

Comment: can you give me an example of that????

i am still trying to implement this but without sucess even now.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the image button you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following line of code :

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//link[@rel='icon' and contains(@href,'favicon-sanofi.png')"))).Click();
```